# How to change QGIS install paths on Windows?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I will be installing QGIS on client machines soon, and we need to have the .qgis2 folder on the D:\ and not to C. (Windows 7)

Is there a way at install time to have it moved to a specific location?

Or, is there a way to delete the installed locaiton and change the path on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [OSGeo4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (choice of 32 and 64 bit), select the 'Advanced Install' option and then you can specify the install location.  You also have more control over what else is installed (such as GRASS, some libraries for certain raster formats like MrSID and ECW etc).

The installer is quite 'clever' and will notify you of (and by default install) any dependencies you also need based on your choices of software.  So if you are not sure, do not be alarmed by the vast range of choices, just expand the 'Desktop' option and select QGIS there (plus any extras).